# Build Different Docker images from different Dockerfiles in same github repo using jenkins pipeline

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

My docker repo has various folders like mongo,maven each has separate dockerfiles.
I need to execute the jenkins pipeline for all the folders ie dockerfiles...
My current setup is using parameter i am selecting individual folder like maven to build the maven image.

How to build all the dockerfiles?

Answer (score 0):

I think a simple shell script should do what you need. Get all folders and execute docker build there. For example something like:

```
ls -d */ | xargs -I {} bash -c "cd '{}' && docker build ."
```

Comment: Thanks ...In shell this will work..I am using docker pipeline plugin... so like this.     docker.build(“my-image:$buildid”)